# getting specific columns from sql statement

Tags: mysql

TO show indexes we use the following query,

```
show indexes from student;
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| student |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | ROLL_NO     | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| student |          1 | stu_roll_no_age_index |            1 | ROLL_NO     | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| student |          1 | stu_roll_no_age_index |            2 | AGE         | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+--------------+
```

Now I am trying to select only Table from the above as follows,

```
select Table, Key_name, Column_name,Index_type from (show indexes from student);
```

I think I might be wrong but  I am not getting how to reason it? Please tell me.
And also , how do I get only specific columns from the result of such query.

Comment: You can not do this. Try Sysindexes rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table `STATISTICS` from db `information_schema`, like this:

```
select TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, INDEX_TYPE
from information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'student';
```

Comment: Nice one.. It worked. :).. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Your approach wasn't wrong, it's just impossible to select something from `show index` query.